# Classes can not be resolved when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jakarta-ee

I am debugging a java web application running on JBoss 6 using Eclipse. I am not remote debugging. When I try to inspect the value of any variable (Strings etc.), I get the message "The type javax.el.ELResolver cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files".

The strange thing is, the problem only happens when inspecting variables. The application itself does not seem to miss any classes.

How can I make inspecting variable values work again?

Comment: Add respective jars and clean and build project.

Comment: As I wrote, the problem is only when inspecting variables. So everything needed is in the build path of the project. The application runs fine, but I can not inspect variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because eclipse cannont locate the JBoss runtime. Add the JBoss runtime to the classpath:

Project->Properties-> Java Build Path-> Libraries -> Add library -> JBoss runtime

Comment: Thanks for your response, but what should I need the sources for? It doesn't make sense to me, as eclipse says the type is not found, not the sources.

Comment: The problem is not about showing the source, it happens when I try to inspect the value of a variable.

Comment: I am using JBoss, I start it within eclipse, so I am not remote debugging.

Comment: Great, this works. I added the server runtime to the project containing the file I was debugging. If you edit your answer or make a new one, I can accept it.